# How can I use a Z-wave switch as a 3-way with no neutral?

Tags: switch, home-automation, dimmer-switch

I have two lights controlled by two light switches in a 3 way switch loop configuration with no neutral.  I would like to replace either one (if I can get away with it) or both of the switches with a Z-wave light switch. From my research, it appears that almost all Z-wave light switches require a neural wire.

I have found a couple of non Z-Wave dimmer switches which claim to not require a neutral.  This [Lutron](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CAO4VTK) switch claims to work with a variety of bulbs and not require a neutral.

Do I have any Z-wave options given that I do not have a neutral?

Here is a picture of one of the switches

[image]

Comment: Ok, but there's a neutral *in the box*, right? They're commonly just nutted together, but they're there. See http://www.askmediy.com/wp-content/uploads/3-way.jpg.

Comment: Sorry about the comment deletes. I was confused myself for a minute there. Do clarify, though: Are there in fact no neutral wires in the switch boxes?

Comment: @isherwood If power comes to the light first, it's possible to have no neutral at either switch. If power is at one switch, it's possible for there to be no neutral at the other switch. Newer codes require a neutral at all switch locations, for this exact reason.

Comment: @Isherwood there is not a fourth neutral wire; just two travelers and a common like in the picture you posted.  Here is a [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmy4T.jpg) of one of the switches.

Comment: I'm confused by this question. You appear to want a Z-Wave compatible device, but it doesn't seem that either of the products you linked to are Z-Wave. Are you willing to pull new cable, or are you simply looking for a device that will work in your current situation?

Comment: Ah, and end-of-run scenario. If I was actually an electrician I'd have known that. :)

Comment: @Tester I am looking for any Z-wave options; I will correct the post.

Comment: @codechurn If that's the case, it sounds like this is a "*shop for me*" type question, which are off topic here.

Comment: If you can validate exactly the way that the lights and switches are configured, it's possible that the existing wires could be re-connected in such a way to provide a neutral and work with Z-wave switches.

Comment: @longneck what would you need to see, the other switch and the connections in the two light fixtures?

Comment: @codechurn at a minimum, the other switch -- it depends on where power comes in at

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a 3-way replaced with a Z-wave combination from Leviton (R02-DZS15 and VP0SR-10Z). The switch requires constant communication with the hub and thus needs power. If you look carefully at the wiring diagram for the Z-wave switches, you will notice that there is a live+neutral powering the switch and a circuit breaking wiring to the light to turn it on-off. Thus, IMHO, you cannot have a Z-wave switch without a neutral wire. Fortunately, in my case there was a neutral wire in one of the boxes and the electrician was able to pull one to the other box.

Trust me once you set the z-wave switch with a hub and program it to work, the additional cost of fishing a neutral wire will be really worth it.

Answer (score 0):

There are and have been several Z-wave switches available.  They are less common and more expensive than the garden-variety ones.  A quick Google search didn't turn up any neutral-free three-way switches, but you could use a wireless battery operated switch to replace one of the three way ones.

Two examples are:

- [GE 45606 Z-Wave Technology 2-Way Dimmer Switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0013V3C4Q)
- [Leviton VRS05-1LZ Vizia RF+ Incandescent Switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001HT6NKO)